# Multiple versions of COM object on same server

Tags: asp-classic, com

I maintain a large ASP classic web site (no budget to convert to ASP.NET). It uses COM objects, written in C#. I need to run multiple sites (Production, UAT, QA) on the one web server.

I would like to be able to have each site run different versions of the code base. That would mean having a separate version of the same COM object per site.

However, it looks like COM objects get registered in the server's registry, with no support for separate versions.

How can I use different version of the same COM object with my site running on the same web server?

Comment: You should be able to use "Registration Free COM" (google is your friend), it can also be used for side-by-side. But it still depends on how your COM objects are written.

Comment: Is not it an option to use different ProgIDs and GUIDs for different versions of objects within the same library. e.g. `Mylib.Obj` for production, `Mylib.Obj.dev` for development and so on?

Comment: @Kul-Tigin What I meant with versions is for example version 1 of the XYZ object being used with the Production site, while a newer version 2 of the same XYZ object is being used with the UAT site - with both sites running on the same server.

During the development process, I don't want developers to have to remember to update a GUID each time they make a change, because they'll forget and there will be chaos.

Comment: So it's not an option I see. Then @SimonMourier suggestion is good but ASP Classic lacks of built-in support to use Registration-Free COM objects. The only way is `CreateObject` and it completely relies on the registry, no exceptions. If it's the way you go, it looks like you'll need to create your own COM factory to instantiate different versions of Registration-Free COM objects.